# how to check for duplicate annotation on map

Tags: iphone, ios, maps

I am working on mapview but when I drop an annotation pin on the map, it's creating duplicate entries for the location of latitude and longitude.

Now I want it so that the user should be able to drop one annotation pin for one latitude and longitude. It means I want to avoid duplicate entries for the same location.

How to do that?

Comment: @rohan: ofcourse rohan if the answer works for me surely i accept that as i have done before....

Answer (score 12):

Annotation is a point of interest. Two annotations could be termed as same when their coordinates are same.
You have to check if the annotation's coordinate is same as any other existing annotation's coordinate.

In case you are talking about annotations overlapping on zoom levels (even though their coordinates are different) then the following links might help you:-

[How can I group MKAnnotations automatically regarding zoom level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194646/how-can-i-group-mkannotations-automatically-regarding-zoom-level)

[Grouped/Ungroup MKAnnotation depending on the zoom level (And keep it fast)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132207/grouped-ungroup-mkannotation-depending-on-the-zoom-level-and-keep-it-fast)